# Header navigation to history php

Tags: php, javascript

I generally use `header("location:xyz.php")` but this time I want to navigate to history. I have more than 10 pages from where user navigate to single file and I want to navigate him back to history that is out of 10 pages. If it is button I use `history.go(-1);return false;` So using this at place of file name in header is correct?

or any other way I navigate him back to history?

Comment: js only, and wont work for all people\browsers, unless you track them on your site with sessions\cookies

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there's a better way than working with history. HTTP is stateless. Server-side should not be concerned about where the user has been (because if you do, you would be handling more complexities such as multiple and concurrent windows/tabs).

If you wish to redirect the user back to where he/she came from, maybe you want to include a `back` GET parameter.

#### page1.php

```
<a href="page2.php?r=page1.php">Go next page...</a>
```

#### page2.php

```
<?php

// do some work and PLEASE: sanitize $_GET

header('Location: ' . $_GET['r']);

?>
```

Comment: But in this condition I am also getting more variables with page1. I mean I have 4 variables with page1 other four variables with page2

Comment: It's best you now re-look at your entire application design. there must be ways you can simplify things. Sometimes if you need to pass so many parameters to get the job done, you have to.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not run javascript inside a header.

Javascript can only run once it is in an HTML page. The header is not even HTML, it has its own rules.

You could deliver a very small page with the javascript: `history.go(-2);` (-2, one for the current page, and one for the page you actually want to go to).